# React Input field keeps reverting to default text after being replaced

Tags: javascript, reactjs, puppeteer

I have the following input field I'm trying to implement in test automation:

```
< input id="chart-name" name="chartName" type="text" value="New Chart">
```

I have tried several ways to type in, replace, backspace, etc. change the input value. But when the page$eval or page.evaluate completes. The input field reverts back to "New Chart".

Here's me attempts so far.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    const chartName = document.getElementById('chart-name');
    chartName.value = 'fooBAR!';
});
```

or

```
await page.$eval('input#chart-name', el => el.value = 'SNAFU!');
```

or

```
await page.click('input#chart-name');
await page.type('input#chart-name', 'This is the chart name box'); // this appends the default
```

or how about we backspace the characters first? This one does nothing...

```
const inputValue = await page.$eval('input#chart-name', el => el.value);
for (let i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
    await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
}
```

And several permutations of the above solutions. Still trying.... any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `value="New Chart"`, it's called controlled Input. You can search that in react website, there's a good article talking about what is controlled and what is not.

Therefore you can't code a fixed value there, because it's same as

```
   const value = '123'

   <input value={value} />
```

If you remove `value` part, your test will work. But that probably won't do anything because you want to change the value, so the interface has to be

```
   <Component value={value} />
```

Here Component could be `input` or any component you want, but value can not be hard coded, it'll have to be passed into it and `onChange` is another prop to change it. These are generic interface to a typical input.